# NSXMLElement walk through

Tags: nsxmlparser

I have an element of a NSXMLDocument (a FCPX exported .fcpxml) which I'd like to walk-through, as opposed to getting the children and then the nested children, etc:

```
    <spine>  
     <clip name="Referee" offset="0s" duration="5s" format="r2" tcFormat="NDF">  
      <video offset="0s" ref="r3" duration="418132800/90000s">  
       <audio lane="-2" offset="0s" ref="r3" srcID="2" duration="3345062400/720000s" role="dialogue" srcCh="1, 2"/>  
       <audio lane="-1" offset="0s" ref="r3" duration="3345062400/720000s" role="dialogue" srcCh="1, 2"/>  
      </video>  
      <spine lane="1" offset="119/25s" format="r1">  
       <clip name="Referee" offset="0s" duration="403200/90000s" start="1300/2500s" format="r2" tcFormat="NDF">  
        <adjust-volume amount="-96dB"/>  
        <video offset="0s" ref="r3" duration="418132800/90000s">  
         <audio lane="-2" offset="0s" ref="r3" srcID="2" duration="3345062400/720000s" role="dialogue" srcCh="1, 2"/>  
         <audio lane="-1" offset="0s" ref="r3" duration="3345062400/720000s" role="dialogue" srcCh="1, 2"/>  
        </video>  
       </clip>  
       <transition name="Cross Dissolve" offset="313200/90000s" duration="1s">  
        <filter-video ref="r4" name="Cross Dissolve">  
         <param name="Look" key="1" value="11 (Video)"/>  
         <param name="Amount" key="2" value="50"/>  
         <param name="Ease" key="50" value="2 (In &amp; Out)"/>  
         <param name="Ease Amount" key="51" value="0"/>  
        </filter-video>  
        <filter-audio ref="r5" name="Audio Crossfade"/>  
       </transition>  
      </spine>  
     </clip>  
     <transition name="Cross Dissolve" offset="4s" duration="1s">  
      <filter-video ref="r4" name="Cross Dissolve">  
       <param name="Look" key="1" value="11 (Video)"/>  
       <param name="Amount" key="2" value="50"/>  
       <param name="Ease" key="50" value="2 (In &amp; Out)"/>  
       <param name="Ease Amount" key="51" value="0"/>  
      </filter-video>  
      <filter-audio ref="r5" name="Audio Crossfade"/>  
     </transition>  
    </spine>
```

I'm thinking that using NSXMLParser would be the best bet, so I've one up like this:

```
NSXMLParser *new_parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithBytes:[[theXMLElement stringValue] UTF8String] length:[theXMLElement stringValue].length]];  
[new_parser setDelegate:self];  
BOOL parse_success = [new_parser parse];
```

But it fails as the `-stringValue` of the element returns a zero-length string (checked with a NSLog output). So how should I setup to parse just the above element (or similar) of a larger NSXMLDocument?

Answer (score 0):

I should have used `-XMLString` to get a valid string for the parser. I'd seen `-stringValue` somewhere and it had become stuck in my head.